# How can I merge geometries in A-Frame without losing material information?

Tags: aframe

I have a large set of block objects using a custom geometry, that I am hoping to merge into a smaller number of larger geometries, as I believe this will reduce rendering costs.

I have been following guidance here: https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/best-practices.html#performance which has led me to the geometry-merger component here:
https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/geometry-merger/

The A-Frame docs say:
"You can use geometry-merger and then make use a three.js material with vertex colors enabled. three.js geometries keep data such as color, uvs per vertex."

The geometry-merger component also says:
"Useful if using vertex or face coloring as individual geometries' colors can still be manipulated individually since this component keeps a faceIndex and vertexIndex."

However I have a couple of problems.

1. If I set vertexColors on my material (as suggested by the A-Frame docs), then this ruins the appearance of my blocks.
2. Whether or not I set vertexColors on my material, all material information seems to be lost when the geometries are merged, and everything just ends up white.

See this glitch for a demonstration of both problems.
https://tundra-mercurial-garden.glitch.me/

My suspicion is that the A-Frame geometry-merger component just won't do what I need here, and I need to implement something myself using the underlying three.js functions.

Is that right, or is there a way that I could make this work using geometry-merger?

Answer (score 3):

For the `vertexColors` to work, you need to have your vertices coloured :) 
More specifically - the BufferGeometry expects an array of `rgb` values for each vertex - which will be used as color for the material.

---

In this bit of code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
var mat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
```

The mesh will be be black unless the geometry contains information about the vertex colors:

```
// create a color attribute in the geometry
geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(vertices_count), 3));
// grab the array
const colors = this.geometry.attributes.color.array;

// fill the array with rgb values
const faceColor = new THREE.Color(color_hex);
for (var i = 0; i < vertices_count / 3; i += 3) {
   colors[i + 0] = faceColor.r; // lol +0
   colors[i + 1] = faceColor.g;
   colors[i + 2] = faceColor.b;
}
// tell the geometry to update the color attribute
geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
```

---

I can't make the `buffer-geometry-merger` component work for some reason, but It's core seems to be valid:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("merger", {
  init: function() {
    // replace with an event where all child entities are ready
    setTimeout(this.mergeChildren.bind(this), 500);
  },
  mergeChildren: function() {
   const geometries = [];
   // traverse the child and store all geometries.
   this.el.object3D.traverse(node => {
     if (node.type === "Mesh") {
       const geometry = node.geometry.clone();
       geometry.applyMatrix4(node.parent.matrix);
       geometries.push(geometry)

       // dispose the merged meshes 
       node.parent.remove(node);
       node.geometry.dispose();
       node.material.dispose();
     }
   }); 
   // create a mesh from the "merged" geometry         
   const mergedGeo = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);
   const mergedMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffffff, roughness: 0.3, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors});
    
   const mergedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeo, mergedMaterial);
   this.el.object3D.add(mergedMesh)
 }
})
```

You can check it out in [this glitch](https://stack-66178788.glitch.me/). There is also an example on using the vertex colors [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_colors.html) ([source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_geometry_colors.html)).

Comment: afaik instancing as well requires a color attribute in the geometry if you want different colors.

Comment: My original approach to coloring (materials applied to Groups configured on the geometry) appears to be working fine with Instanced Meshes.

E.g.
https://slow-guttural-cemetery.glitch.me/

See also: https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/instanced-mesh

Comment: @DiarmidMackenzie correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you have three pools of the same cube but with different materials - what i meant in my comment is creating a single instanced mesh capable of having different colors for its instances

Comment: OK understood.  What I meant was that within each mesh, I have 2 different colors: the black frame & the face color.

That allows me to get draw calls down from 2N = where N is the number of blocks to 2K where K is the number of colors.  That's  enough of a performance boost for my needs.

In your remix of the glitch, you have got the number of calls even lower, but moving to vertex coloring seems to have lost the black frames?

Comment: @DiarmidMackenzie I'll try to make a solid example but Its easier said than done and will take a while (I do have an Idea for instanced meshes, but for mergers I need to test it out a bit).

Answer (score 1):

I agree it sounds like you need to consider other solutions. Here are two different instances of instancing with A-Frame:

- https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-instancing
- https://github.com/EX3D/aframe-InstancedMesh

Neither are perfect or even fully finished, but can hopefully get you started as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Although my original question was about geometry merging, I now believe that Instanced Meshes were a better solution in this case.

Based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66178932/15086095) I implemented this new A-Frame Component:
https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/instanced-mesh

This glitch shows the scene from the original glitch being rendered with just 19 calls using this component. That compares pretty well with > 200 calls that would have been required if every object were rendered individually.
https://dull-stump-psychology.glitch.me/

A key limitation is that I was not able to use a single mesh for all the different block colors, but had to use one mesh per color (7 meshes total).

InstancedMesh can support different colored elements, but each element must have a single color, whereas the elements in this scene had 2 colors each (black frame + face color).